# Musical Shape on music stand

Tags: history

[image]

I've seen this shape a few times, but what exactly does it represents?

Comment: the lyra is the symbol for music: banners, uniforms, concert programs, flyers etc:
https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBH_deCH697CH697&biw=1230&bih=562&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=AkzQXJCMAuPjgwfdxoqoCw&q=lyra+symbol+for+music&oq=lyra+symbol+for+music&gs_l=img.3...6352.12492..12755...2.0..0.98.1611.19......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i67j0j0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24.Hl_zQH0MVs0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a [lyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyre) of some kind:

[image]
[image]

A lot of ancient civilizations used variations of this instrument, especially the ancient Greeks. It's similar to a small harp .